# Analyzing Numerical Error in C++ Function

Tags: floating-point, c++

Suppose that I have a function that takes as input several floating-point values (single or double), does some computation, and produces output floating-point values (also single or double). I am working primarily with MSVC 2008, but also plan to work with MinGW/GCC. I'm programming in C++.

**What is the typical way of programmatically measuring how much error is in the results? Assuming that I need to use an arbitrary precision library: what is the best such library if I don't care about speed?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're looking for a good bound on your rounding error, you don't necessarily need an aribtrary-precision library. You can use running error analysis instead.

I wasn't able to find a good online reference, but it's all described in Section 3.3 of Nick Higham's book "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms". The idea is quite simple:

1. Re-factor your code so that you have a single assignment of a single arithmetic operation on each line.
2. For each variable, e.g. `x`, create a variable `x_err` which is initialized to zero when `x` is assigned a constant.
3. For each operation, e.g. `z = x * y`, update the variable `z_err` using the standard model of floating-point arithmetic and the resulting `z` and the running errors `x_err` and `y_err`.
4. The return value of your function should then also have a respective `_err` value attached to it. This is a data-dependent bound on your total roundoff error.

The tricky part is step 3. For the most simple arithmetic operations, you can use the following rules:

- `z = x + y` -> `z_err = u*abs(z) + x_err + y_err`
- `z = x - y` -> `z_err = u*abs(z) + x_err + y_err`
- `z = x * y` -> `z_err = u*abs(z) + x_err*abs(y) + y_err*abs(x)`
- `z = x / y` -> `z_err = u*abs(z) + (x_err*abs(y) + y_err*abs(x))/y^2`
- `z = sqrt(x)` -> `z_err = u*abs(z) + x_err/(2*abs(z))`

where `u = eps/2` is the unit roundoff. Yes, the rules for `+` and `-` are the same. Rules for any other operation `op(x)` can be easily extracted using the Taylor series expansion of the result applied to `op(x + x_err)`. Or you can try googling. Or using Nick Higham's book.

As an example, consider the following Matlab/Octave code which evaluates a polynomials in the coefficients `a` at a point `x` using the Horner scheme:

```
function s = horner ( a , x )
    s = a(end);
    for k=length(a)-1:-1:1
        s = a(k) + x*s;
    end
```

For the first step, we split-up the two operations in `s = a(k) + x*s`:

```
function s = horner ( a , x )
    s = a(end);
    for k=length(a)-1:-1:1
        z = x*s;
        s = a(k) + z;
    end
```

We then introduce the `_err` variables. Note that the inputs `a` and `x` are assumed to be exact, but we could just as well also require the user to pass corresponding values for `a_err` and `x_err`:

```
function [ s , s_err ] = horner ( a , x )
    s = a(end);
    s_err = 0;
    for k=length(a)-1:-1:1
        z = x*s;
        z_err = ...;
        s = a(k) + z;
        s_err = ...;
    end
```

Finally, we apply the rules described above to get the error terms:

```
function [ s , s_err ] = horner ( a , x )
    u = eps/2;
    s = a(end);
    s_err = 0;
    for k=length(a)-1:-1:1
        z = x*s;
        z_err = u*abs(z) + s_err*abs(x);
        s = a(k) + z;
        s_err = u*abs(s) + z_err;
    end
```

Note that since we have no `a_err` or `x_err`, e.g. they are assumed to be zero, the respective terms are simply ignored in the error expressions.

Et voilà! We now have a Horner scheme which returns a data-dependent error estimate (note: this is an *upper bound* on the error) alongside the result.

As a side note, since you're using C++, you might consider making your own class for floating-point values which carries around the `_err` term and overloading all the arithmetic operations to update these values as described above. For large codes, this may be the easier, albeit computationally less efficient, route. Having said that, you may be able to find such a class online. A quick Google search gave me [this link](http://ctn.cvut.cz/ap/download.php?id=497).

P.S. Note that this all works only on machines adhering strictly to IEEE-754, i.e. all arithmetic operations are precise to $\pm u$. This analysis also gives a tighter, more realistic bound than using interval arithmetic since, by definition, you can not represent a number $x(1 \pm u)$ in floating point, i.e. your interval would just round to the number itself.

Comment: +1 for this analysis, because it is interesting. I like Higham's work. What concerns me is that requiring a user to write that extra code by hand (instead of semi-automatically like interval arithmetic) could be error prone as the number of numerical operations becomes large.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry: I completely agree with the complexity issue. For larger codes I would strongly recommend writing a class/datatype which overloads operations on doubles such as to only have to implement each operation correctly once. I'm quite surprised that there doesn't seem to be something like this for Matlab/Octave.

Comment: I like this analysis, but since the computation of the error terms are also performed in floating-point, won't those error terms be imprecise due to floating-point errors?

Comment: @plasmacel Yes, but the error caused by these imprecise operations will be O(u^2), which is the same order of the error you are already neglecting because of Taylor expansions.

Comment: Also note that this is basically ball arithmetic, a variant of interval arithmetic.

Answer (score 10):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (i.e., the GNU Multiple Precision library) is the best arbitrary precision library that I know of.

I don't know of any programmatic way to measure the error in the results of an arbitrary floating point function. One thing you could try is to calculate an interval extension of a function using [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). In C++, you would have to use some sort of library to calculate the interval extensions; one such library is the [Boost Interval Arithmetic Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm). Basically, to measure the error, you would supply as arguments to your function intervals that have a width of 2 times unit roundoff (roughly), centered at the values of interest, and then your output would be a collection of intervals, the width of which would give you some conservative estimate of the error. A difficulty with this approach is that interval arithmetic used in this fashion can overestimate error by significant amounts, but this approach is the most "programmatic" one I can think of.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed interval arithmetic mentioned in your answer... Upvoted!

Comment: Richard Harris wrote an excellent series of articles in the [ACCU](http://accu.org/) journal *Overload* about the [Floating Point Blues](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/101197/22493). His article about *interval arithmetic* is in [Overload 103](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c297/) ([pdf](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload103.pdf), p19-24).

Answer (score 9):

A nice portable and open source library for arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic (and much else) is [Victor Shoup's NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-intro.html), which is available in C++ source form.

At a lower level is the [GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/), also an open source package.

NTL can be used with GMP is faster performance is required, but NTL provides its own base routines that are certainly usable if you "don't care about speed".  GMP claims to be the "fastest bignum library".  GMP is largely written in C, but has a C++ interface.

**Added:** While interval arithmetic can give upper and lower bounds on the exact answer in an automated way, this doesn't accurately measure the error in a "standard" precision computation because the interval size typically grows with each operation (either in a relative or absolute error sense).

The typical way of finding error size, either for rounding errors or for errors of discretization, etc., is to compute an extra precision value and compare that to the "standard" precision value.  Only modest extra precision is needed to determine the error size itself to reasonable accuracy, since the rounding errors alone are substantially larger in "standard" precision than they are in the extra precision computation.

The point can be illustrated by comparing single and double precision computations.  Note that in C++ intermediate expressions are always computed in (at least) double precision, so if we want to illustrate what a computation in "pure" single precision would be like, we need to store out the intermediate values in single precision.

**C code snippet**

```
    float fa,fb;
    double da,db,err;
    fa = 4.0;
    fb = 3.0;
    fa = fa/fb;
    fa -= 1.0;

    da = 4.0;
    db = 3.0;
    da = da/db;
    da -= 1.0;

    err = fa - da;
    printf("Single precision error wrt double precision value\n");
    printf("Error in getting 1/3rd is %e\n",err);
    return 0;
```

The output from above (Cygwin/MinGW32 GCC tool chain):

```
Single precision error wrt double precision value
Error in getting 1/3rd is 3.973643e-08
```

Thus the error is about what one expects in rounding 1/3rd to single precision.  One would not (I'd suspect) care about getting more than a couple of decimal places *in the error* correct, since measurement of the error is for magnitude and not for exactitude.

Comment: Your approach is definitely mathematically sound. I think the tradeoff is in rigor; people who are pedantic about error will point to the rigor of interval arithmetic, but I suspect that in many applications, computing to extra precision would be enough, and the resulting error estimates would likely be tighter, as you point out.

Comment: This is the approach I was imagining that I would use. I might try a few of these different techniques to see which is most appropriate for my application. The code example update is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

**Rigorous and automatic error estimation** can be achieved by [interval analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). You work with intervals instead of numbers. For example addition:

```
[a,b] + [c,d] = [min(a+c, a+d, b+c, b+d), max (a+c, a+d, b+c, b+d)] = [a+c, b+d]
```

Round-off can also be handled rigorously, see [Rounded interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Rounded_interval_arithmetic).

As long as your input consists of narrow intervals, the estimates are OK and are faily cheap to compute. Unfortunately, the error is often overestimated, see the [dependence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Dependency_problem).

I do not know of any arbitrary precision interval arithmetic library.

It depends on your problem at hand whether interval arithmetic can serve your needs or not.

Answer (score 4):

The [GNU MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/) is an arbitrary-precision float library that has high accuracy (in particular, correct rounding for all operations, which is not as easy as it sounds) as one of their main focus points. It uses GNU MP under the hood. It has an extension called [MPFI](https://gforge.inria.fr/projects/mpfi/) that does interval arithmetic, which - as [Geoff's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1010/49) suggests - might come in handy for verification purposes: keep increasing the working precision until the resulting interval falls within small bounds.

This won't always work, though; in particular it's not necessarily effective if you're doing something like numerical integration, where every step carries an "error" independent of rounding problems. In that case, try a specialized package such as [COSY infinity](http://bt.pa.msu.edu/index_cosy.htm) which does this very well using specific algorithms to bound the integration error (and using so-called Taylor models instead of intervals).

Comment: I agree; numerical integration is definitely a case where naïve interval arithmetic can go awry. However, even Taylor models use interval arithmetic. I am familiar with Makino and Berz's work, and I believe they use Taylor model in the sense of R. E. Moore, although they also use tricks involving what they call "differential algebra".

Comment: @GeoffOxberry: Yeah - I think this differential algebra is stuff to get a bound on the error in the integration step.

Answer (score 1):

@Pedro mentioned running error analysis and introduced the math for propagating error while accounting for unit roundoff. They also gave a Matlab/Octave implementation. @plasmacel noticed that in this implementation, the error terms themselves were being computed using floating point values, which also have roundoff error which are not being accounted for.

This might be overkill for most purposes, but this C++ implementation strictly accounts for all round-offs in every operation, even when computing the error terms themselves:

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559);

float unit_round_off(float result) {
    return std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() * result / 2;
}

void mul_w_err(float* r, float a, float b, float* r_err_output, float a_err, float b_err) {
    // r_err = a_err * b + b_err * a + a_err * b_err
    *r = a * b;
    float r_err = unit_round_off(*r);

    float term1 = a_err * b;
    term1 += unit_round_off(term1);

    float term2 = b_err * a;
    term2 += unit_round_off(term2);

    float term3 = a_err * b_err;
    term3 += unit_round_off(term3);

    float term12 = term1 + term2;
    term12 += unit_round_off(term12);

    float term3r = term3 + r_err;
    term3r += unit_round_off(term3r);

    float complete_err = term12 + term3r;
    complete_err += unit_round_off(complete_err);

    *r_err_output = complete_err;
}

void __add_sub_w_err_funct(float* r, float a, float b, float* r_err_output, float a_err, float b_err) {
    // being careful to round the floating point error up after every binary op
    float r_err = unit_round_off(*r);
    
    float ab_err_sum = a_err + b_err;
    ab_err_sum += unit_round_off(ab_err_sum);

    float abr_err_sum = r_err + ab_err_sum;
    abr_err_sum += unit_round_off(abr_err_sum);

    *r_err_output = abr_err_sum;
}

void add_w_err(float* r, float a, float b, float* r_err_output, float a_err, float b_err) {
    // r_err = a_err + b_err
    *r = a + b;
    __add_sub_w_err_funct(r, a, b, r_err_output, a_err, b_err);
}

void sub_w_err(float* r, float a, float b, float* r_err_output, float a_err, float b_err) {
    // r_err = a_err + b_err
    *r = a - b;
    __add_sub_w_err_funct(r, a, b, r_err_output, a_err, b_err);
}
```

Comment: Aren't those expressions for the errors in multiplication and division up to O(u^2) terms? In that case even this implementation is not accounting for all errors rigorously. For instance, `r_err = a_err * b + b_err * a` should rather be `r_err = a_err * b + b_err * a + a_err * b_err` (but division is trickier).

Comment: I'm don't understand where the `a_err * b_err` term is coming from. My assumption (which I should have clarified) is that `a_err` and `b_err` inputs are already rounded up.

Comment: It comes from the identity $(a+a_{err})(b+b_{err}) - ab = a_{err}b + b_{err}a + a_{err}b_{err}$, which I assume you are using to bound the error in multiplication.

Comment: I see! I was following the link pedro mentioned. Turns out that term is usually omitted since it is so small, which would be incorrect to do in our case. Thank you for pointing this out. I have fixed the mul function, and removed the div function since I don't have time to correct it right now, but anyone who sees this answer can follow the same methods to derive similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am told that MPIR is a good library to use if you are working with Visual Studio:

http://mpir.org/

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Could you add some details on how this library can be used to measure the error of floating point computations?

Comment: I will try; I actually haven't set up MPIR just yet on my computer just yet! I have set up GMP and MPFR.